# Defining global variables in TypeScript for WeChat mini program

Tags: typescript, dom, wechat, javascript-scope, wechat-miniprogram

Dear StackOverflow users,

I made a module for both **browser** and **WeChat mini program**.
That module is written in multiple TypeScript and is compiled to one minified file.
In that module, I need to use DOM/BOM APIs such as `document`, 'window`, 'navigator`.
On the browser, loading and using the compiled single-file have no problem.

But on the WeChat mini-program, there's no `global` object as on Node. Nor there's no `document` and `window` global objects as on browser.
To fix this, I made two build commands for each environment.

- `grunt build`, standard TS compilation for browser
- `grunt wx_build`, standard TS compilation and append patch code for WeChat mini program

The patched js file looks like:

```js
// mymodule-bundle.min.js

// patch
window=require("./miniapp-adapter/src/index.js");
document=require("./miniapp-adapter/src/document.js").default;

// original compiled/minified code
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined")...
```

On WeChat mini program project, I put `mymodule-bundle.min.js` and `miniapp-adapter` in the same folder. As a result, I could port my HTML5 app to WeChat mini program.

But I want a smarter way to do that.

> **How can I declare the `window` or `document` global variable in `mymodule.ts` for WeChat mini-program runtime?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you declare them:

```
declare const document: any
declare const window: any
```

To get better types on them for intellisense you just make them of the type that represents what you have put there, if you need consumers to use them. Otherwise you can leave them like that.

In Node you can do this:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    window: any
    document: any
  }
}

global.window = require("./miniapp-adapter/src/index.js");
global.document = require("./miniapp-adapter/src/document.js").default;
```

To be idiomatic on Node, though, you should export them from a module, rather than loading them into the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you. I included that code to `mymodule.ts`. But how to set that `window` constant as defined in another js module (miniapp-adapter)? For example, `window = require(...)` causes error, because `window` is defined as a constant.

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: The runtime of WeChat mini-program is different from Node or Browser. There's no `global` or `window`, `document` global variables. Instead, there's `wx` global variable.  I use HammerJS and Three.js in `mymodule`, thus I need `document` and `window` as global. `global.document` is not needed. But when I try to make them, TS compiler raises error, as there already defiend global `document` and `window` in built-in type definitions.

Comment: That's why I patched the compiled js manually. I'm asking __how to make global 'document` and `window` while keeping the normal TS compile options for the browser env__.

Comment: I'm __not__ asking it for Node nor Browser.

Comment: I see, this: https://walkthechat.com/wechat-mini-programs-simple-introduction/

Comment: Hmmm, you can remove the DOM typing. See this tsconfig here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/delay/issues/40#issuecomment-425493713

Comment: Do you need DOM typings in your project for intellisense, or do you just want to erase them to allow you to define them if they don't exist at runtime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208308/discussion-between-josh-wulf-and-hotte-shen).